# Create fragment after receiving intent from activity?On post excute maybe?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-asynctask, oncreate

I currently have an activity that after receiving a list of objects it should create the fragment. However, I realised I can't put all of this in onCreate because it might create the fragment first then get the intent?But I'm not sure how to do the onPostExecute and onDoinbackground?

In my onCreate function.

```
 monitor_list= this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("monitorList");

        this.cholesterol_monitor = (ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>) monitor_list;





        monitorListFragment = MonitorListFragment.newInstance(cholesterol_monitor);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_monitor_layout, monitorListFragment)
                .commit();
```